# How to access node data attribute inside jstree sort function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

### Introduction

I am displaying tree using `jquery` tree plugin library `jstree`.

### Expectation

As i am displying files - they have extensions - so ordering by name is not very helpful. One would imagine sorting by type is best.

So to do just that i added data attribute `item-sort-value` that cosinsts of `extension + fileName + uuid`.

### Error

I would like to sort tree by this field `data-item-sort-value`, but dispay *standard* file name in the tree. Yet i can not get *its value inside the sort function*.

I also tried:

- a1.getAttribute('data-item-sort-value')... got `TypeError: a1.getAttribute is not a function`
- a1.a_attr('data-item-sort-value')... got `TypeError: a1.getAttribute is not a function`
- a1.data('item-sort-value')... got `TypeError: a1.data is not a function`
- a1.node.data('item-sort-value')... got `TypeError: a1.data is not a function`

### My code

```
'sort': function(a, b)
{
    let a1 = this.get_node(a);
    let b1 = this.get_node(b);

    if (a1.node.attr('item-sort-value') === b1.node.attr('data-item-sort-value'))
    {
        return (a1.node.attr('data-item-sort-value') > b1.node.attr('data-item-sort-value')) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (a1.icon > b1.icon) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

### Console output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is working sort function that uses data attribute values.

```
'sort' : function(a, b)
{
    let a1 = this.get_node(a);
    let b1 = this.get_node(b);
    let isv_a1 = a1.a_attr['data-item-sort-value'];
    let isv_b1 = b1.a_attr['data-item-sort-value'];

    return (isv_a1 > isv_b1) ? 1 : -1;
}
```